# Unknown provider: attrsProvider <- attrs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**while accessing attrs from my child controller its gives this error**

```
> Unknown provider: attrsProvider <- attrs
```

**Here is my code:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
//parent controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller, $attrs ) {
//extending child controlller
  angular.extend(this, $controller('MainCtrl2', {$scope: $scope}));
});

//child controller
app.controller('MainCtrl2', function($scope, $controller, $attrs) {
 console.log($attrs)
});
```

**but accesing attrs from the parent controller work fine...**

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the `$attrs` as well.

```
angular.extend(this, $controller('MainCtrl2', {$scope: $scope, $attrs}));
```

Comment: okay thanks for your reply ..... its works fine...... but i need to change over 50 pages... so i am finding another way.